# How to return fully resolved promise?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I am trying to play around with $q, write some tests, try to stub promises etc. and I wondered if there is a way to return fully resolved promise like one can do it with whenjs, when("stuff to return), something that would be equal to this

```
  function fullyResolvedPromise(expectedResponse) {

        var dfd = $q.defer();
        dfd.resolve(expectedResponse);
        $rootScope.$apply();

        return dfd.promise;
    }
```

Clarification: I know this code works, but I want to do it without writing this function. I want to do something like this  $q(expectedresponse) and get equivalent to above code. That is what I am after. Just like with whenjs you can write when(stuffToResolve) and it would return you a fully resolved promise.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Your code is perfect, what doesn't work exactly?

Comment: @Blackhole: See clarification

Comment: related: [How to return a resolved promise from an AngularJS Service using $q?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23567430/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After posting a clarification I re-read the documentation and there it is - when() method.
So I can use $q.when(stuffToResolve) and it would be equal to calling the above function.