# How to return a resolved promise from an AngularJS Service using $q?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-promise

My service is:

```
myApp.service('userService', [
  '$http', '$q', '$rootScope', '$location', function($http, $q, $rootScope, $location) {
    var deferred;
    deferred = $q.defer();
    this.initialized = deferred.promise;
    this.user = {
      access: false
    };
    this.isAuthenticated = function() {
      this.user = {
        first_name: 'First',
        last_name: 'Last',
        email: 'email@address.com',
        access: 'institution'
      };
      return deferred.resolve();
    };
  }
]);
```

I'm calling this in my `config` file via:

```
myApp.run([
  '$rootScope', 'userService', function($rootScope, userService) {
    return userService.isAuthenticated().then(function(response) {
      if (response.data.user) {
        return $rootScope.$broadcast('login', response.data);
      } else {
        return userService.logout();
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

However, it complains that `then` is not a function. Aren't I returning the resolved promise?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From your service method:

```
function serviceMethod() {
    return $timeout(function() {
        return {
            property: 'value'
        };
    }, 1000);
}
```

And in your controller:

```
serviceName
    .serviceMethod()
    .then(function(data){
        //handle the success condition here
        var x = data.property
    });
```

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, you are correct, I was unaware that `$timeout` actually returns a promise, serviceMethod can be shortened to: return $timeout(function() { return {property: 'value'}; }, 1000);

Comment: This may work, but it's certainly not a recommended approach for returning promises

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I did, now returning the promise which $timeout generates.

Comment: Very well, I retracted my -1.

Comment: I tend to agree with Mike, this might work, but the answer below from mccainz better explains the mechanics of creating, resolving and returning a promise. I've added a downvote for this reason.

Comment: @sifriday liking a different answer does not mean another answer is bad. This example shows returning a contrived example of returning a promise, not a way to create promises. Mike's comments were in regards to me using `$q.defer()` instead of utilizing the promise that is generated with $timeout.

Comment: ah ok, but I still agree with his sentiment even if for a different reason! I appreciate a downvote is disheartening, and that we could just use upvotes to help the good content float to the top, but in this case I do feel your answer is not helpful, because it fails to explain the mechanics of $q and instead presents an abstraction of $q. Someone new to promises, or like me familiar with promises but new to Angular, could get totally the wrong end of the stick!

Answer (score 108):

## How to simply return a pre-resolved promise in AngularJS

Resolved promise:

```
return $q.when( someValue );    // angularjs 1.2+
return $q.resolve( someValue ); // angularjs 1.4+, alias to `when` to match ES6
```

Rejected promise:

```
return $q.reject( someValue );
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. A nice short way to return a static value when stubbing out http service calls.

Answer (score 35):

Return your promise , return deferred.promise.
It is the promise API that has the 'then' method.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Calling resolve does not return a promise it only signals the
promise that the promise is resolved so it can execute the 'then' logic.

Basic pattern as follows, rinse and repeat
http://plnkr.co/edit/fJmmEP5xOrEMfLvLWy1h?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.3.0-beta.5" 
        src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div ng-controller="test">
  <button ng-click="test()">test</button>
</div>
<script>
  var app = angular.module("app",[]);

  app.controller("test",function($scope,$q){

    $scope.$test = function(){
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      deferred.resolve("Hi");
      return deferred.promise;
    };

    $scope.test=function(){
      $scope.$test()
      .then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
      });
    }      
  });

  angular.bootstrap(document,["app"]);

</script>
```

Comment: How will the promise get resolved then? The `.then` will never get triggered

Comment: @Shamoon deferred.resolve(); is resolved in the moment you call it because there is no value given in. I would suggest instead of write deferred.resolve("Hi"); just write deferred.resolve(); to get a resolved empty promise. But you could also use $q.when(); to get a resolved thenable empty promise ;-).

Comment: IMHO this is better than the accepted answer, which by using $timeout to generate a promise that will be resolved is failing to show the mechanics of manually creating and resolving promises.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the correct code for your service:

```
myApp.service('userService', [
  '$http', '$q', '$rootScope', '$location', function($http, $q, $rootScope, $location) {

    var user = {
      access: false
    };

    var me = this;

    this.initialized = false;
    this.isAuthenticated = function() {

      var deferred = $q.defer();
      user = {
        first_name: 'First',
        last_name: 'Last',
        email: 'email@address.com',
        access: 'institution'
      };
      deferred.resolve(user);
      me.initialized = true;

      return deferred.promise;
    };
  }
]);
```

Then you controller should align accordingly:

```
myApp.run([
  '$rootScope', 'userService', function($rootScope, userService) {
    return userService.isAuthenticated().then(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        // You have access to the object you passed in the service, not to the response.
        // You should either put response.data on the user or use a different property.
        return $rootScope.$broadcast('login', user.email);  
      } else {
        return userService.logout();
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

Few points to note about the service:

- Expose in a service only what needs to be exposed. User should be kept internally and be accessed by getters only.
- When in functions, use 'me' which is the service to avoid edge cases of this with javascript.
- I guessed what initialized was meant to do, feel free to correct me if I guessed wrong.

Answer (score 2):

To return a resolved promise, you can use:

```
return $q.defer().resolve();
```

If you need to resolve something or return data:

```
return $q.defer().resolve(function(){

    var data;
    return data;

});
```

Comment: I've [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30779102/901944) an even shorter version.

Answer (score 1):

For shorter JavaScript-Code use this:

```
myApp.service('userService', [
  '$q', function($q) {
    this.initialized = $q.when();
    this.user = {
      access: false
    };
    this.isAuthenticated = function() {
      this.user = {
        first_name: 'First',
        last_name: 'Last',
        email: 'email@address.com',
        access: 'institution'
      };
      return this.initialized;
    };
  }
]);
```

You know that you loose the binding to userService.user by overwriting it with a new object instead of setting only the objects properties?

Here is what I mean as a example of my plnkr.co example code (Working example:
http://plnkr.co/edit/zXVcmRKT1TmiBCDL4GsC?p=preview):

```
angular.module('myApp', []).service('userService', [
    '$http', '$q', '$rootScope', '$location', function ($http, $q, $rootScope, $location) {
    this.initialized = $q.when(null);
    this.user = {
        access: false
    };
    this.isAuthenticated = function () {
        this.user.first_name = 'First';
        this.user.last_name = 'Last';
        this.user.email = 'email@address.com';
        this.user.access = 'institution';
        return this.initialized;
    };
}]);

angular.module('myApp').controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'userService', function ($scope, userService) {
    $scope.user = userService.user;
    $scope.callUserService = function () {
        userService.isAuthenticated().then(function () {
            $scope.thencalled = true;
        });
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
myApp.service('userService', [
    '$http', '$q', '$rootScope', '$location', function($http, $q, $rootScope, $location) {
      var deferred= $q.defer();
      this.user = {
        access: false
      };
      try
      {
      this.isAuthenticated = function() {
        this.user = {
          first_name: 'First',
          last_name: 'Last',
          email: 'email@address.com',
          access: 'institution'
        };
        deferred.resolve();
      };
    }
    catch
    {
        deferred.reject();
    }

    return deferred.promise;
  ]);
```

Comment: Could someone tell me why this is marked for downvote?