# How to use $q to return a value of an http request Async (using typescript)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, typescript, q

I have been trying to just set up a simple promise async structure to return the json returned object from an http request and I can't find any good examples of one. I am sure I am doing something horribly wrong, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Here is what I am trying:

```
getjsonObjAsync(): any {
    var deferred: ng.IDeferred<any> = this.$q.defer();
    $.ajax({
        url: AppSettings.jsonObjUrl,
        type: 'get',
    })
    .then((result) => {
        deferred.resolve(result);
    })
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

When I call this method, it returns

```
Object {then: function, catch: function, finally: function}
catch: function (callback) {
finally: function (callback) {
then: function (callback, errback, progressback) {
__proto__: Object
```

But I want it to return the json object I get from the http request, that I can see if I add a console.log(result) here:

```
    })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(result)
        deferred.resolve(result);
    })
```

It seems like I am incorrectly using the $q system, but I can't figure out the right way to return the json object.

I tried to follow the example here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23572025/3757782
but it still fails to return the json object from the reqest

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are returning a `promise` i.e. `return deferred.promise` you need to use the promise at the other end i.e. :

```
getjsonObjAsync().then((result)=>{
    console.log(result);
});
```

PS: prefer `$http` (and `$http.get`) over `$.ajax`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might have misunderstood how promises work. They won't magically turn an asynchronous operation into a synchronous one so unless you want to block you won't be returning JSON from your method.

The `then` property of the object you end up returning with your code is a function that registers a handler for the promise, it's used exactly like you did with the result of the `$.ajax` call.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This definitely helped me solve the problem, (and fix my real problem, which was a lack of understanding) but basarat's answer seems to be the more direct answer.