# how to reject immediately with $q in angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I have a test I want to do before I make an ajax call. If that test is a failure condition I want to immediately reject, but it seems I cannot do that:

```
  svc.test = function(foo){
    var def = $q.defer();

    if (!foo){
      def.reject(new Error('failed'));
    } else {
      // get data via ajax here
      def.resolve({})
    }

    return def.promise;
  };
```

I tried adding `setTimeout` around the `def.reject()` but then my unit test doesn't work.

```
  it.only('should error ', function(){
    return expect(MyServices.test()).to.eventually.be.rejectedWith('failed');
  });
```

Using native promise works fine, but I need to do this with `$q`:

```
  return Promise.reject(new Error('failed'));
```

Comment: I have no idea what `to.eventually.be.rejectedWith` does, but your promise is not rejected with 'failed'. It's rejected with new Error('failed'). Moreover, if you never call $scope.$apply(), the promise will stay pending.

Comment: its from `chai-as-promised` -- the `rejectedWith` expects an error object.

Comment: Then you most probably need to call $scope.$apply() (or $rootScope.$apply()).

Comment: its a service, there is no scope.

Comment: $rootScope is a service, too. Inject it in your test, and call $rootScope.$apply().

Comment: this makes no sense. i'm returning immediately. and $rootScope should not be in services, as I understand it.

Comment: @chovy - this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/9954) deals with your problem, and offer solutions. The problem is tied to  `$apply` as JB Nizet wrote.

Comment: First, it's perfectly fine to use $rootScope from a service. Second, I'm not telling you to call $apply() from your service, but from your test. Third, yes, it makes perfect sense, since angular promises are actually resolved/rejected at the next digest loop. It's documented, you know: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#testing.

Comment: Ok, I got it to resolve, but `chai-as-promised` is just timing out now: `var resolvedValue = MyServices.test(); $rootScope.$apply(); return resolvedValue.should.eventually.be.rejectedWith(TypeError, 'failed');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return a Promise that promises to throw error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33292312/return-a-promise-that-promises-to-throw-error)